# Jquery change select option depending on anchor change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select

I have this piece of code for select option:

```
<select class="select-box" name="select-choice-month" id="select-locations">
  <option id="1">Select Region</option>
  <option id="2" value="eu">Europe</option>
  <option id="3" value="nam">North America</option>
  <option id="4" value="sam">Latin America</option>
  <option id="5" value="aspa">Asia/Pacific</option>
</select>
```

On select change I already have to change its background like this (displaying or hiding specific div):

```
$('#select-locations').change(function() {
    $('#form1, #form2, #form3, #form4, #form5').hide();
    $('#form' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')).show();
});
```

But, now I have mini navigation which is also displaying or hiding same div's

```
<div id="map-menu">
    <a href="#" id="3">North America</a>
    <a href="#" id="4">Latin America</a>
    <a href="#" id="5">Asia/Pacific</a>
</div><!-- end of map-menu -->
```

Jquery for this:

```
$('#map-menu a').click(function() {
    $('#form1, #form2, #form3, #form4, #form5').hide();
    $('#form' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
});
```

How can I achieve when anchor is clicked and div is changed to change output (name) of selected option also? In first example that is working, but when I am changing it through anchors it doesnt work ...

Tnx for any answers

Comment: How about changing the selectbox selection in your map-menu handler? That would also trigger the `change` event and you wouldn't have to write it twice.

Comment: As a side note: 1. Make sure that you don't repeat Ids in your HTML, 2. Add a common css class to your `FormX` elements and use that as a selector.

Comment: Just a note, it helps if you setup a test case with [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/)  That way, people can reproduce your problem instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly then I think the following should solve your problem and reduce code repetition.

```
$('#map-menu a').click(function() {
    $('#select-locations').val(this.id).change();
});
```

It will listen for a click on the `a`s and then set the value of the select list to the clicked `id`. Once this is complete it will trigger the `change` event on the select list causing your `change` listener to be triggered.

Also a note on your `id`s they should not just be a number:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/703790/461813

### Updated work around from comments

If you want to use your current HTML then it would be something like this:

```
$('#map-menu a').click(function() {
    var select = $('#select-locations');
    var option_to_select = $('option[id="' + this.id + '"]', select);
    select.val(option_to_select.val()).change();
});
```

But it should be noted that your code currently does not have unique `id`s so I suggest you namespace them like:

```
select_option_1
anchor_option_1
```

Then the above code would become:

```
$('#map-menu a').click(function() {
    var option_id = this.id.replace('anchor', 'select');
    var select = $('#select-locations');
    var option_to_select = $('option[id="' + option_id + '"]', select);
    select.val(option_to_select.val()).change();
});
```

And here it is as a jsFiddle you can run: http://jsfiddle.net/6tHnj/

Comment: Now everytime when you are using mini navigation it jumps to the first option (Select region) no matter where I click. Also, yes I know about using ID's and numbers at the start of ID. Will change that later :)

Comment: That is because your `id`s need to be the same as your select options values for this to work.

Comment: @Matas see my update answer for some solutions to the issues you are facing.

Comment: thanks mate this is working! Also thanks for any suggestions you made, I will fix that :)