# How to get text from table nested in a list using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have these HTML tags and I need to get the text from the *TDs*. I already have and can use the *ID* of *li* and the *div id* (li and div (nested in li) IDs are the same).

How to get all the TD text only from one table. The input for template 1 for example should be:

> Video, Image

My HTML

```
<div id="slideHolder">
    <ul id="mainList">
                        <li templateid="1">
                           <div id="1">
                                <table >
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>Video</td>
                                    <td>Image</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li templateid="2">
                            <div id="2" >
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td >Text</td>
                                    <td >Image</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML has errors in it. You should fix that.

Comment: How ? and Where? thanks

Comment: You have an extra `"` in `<ul id="mainList" ">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var tdtexts= $("#mainList td").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xHLC5/)**

**Update:** to find td texts in template 1:

```
var tdtexts= $("li[templateid='1'] td").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QJbS6/)**

Comment: but by using Id I need to get only the text from td nested specific in li/div Id with a specific Id

Comment: just replace the id `mainList` with newID.

Comment: Well it looks fine, but I changed in the demo from mainList  to id and got the same result. I need only result from a specific table. The problem is to combain the id in the Jquery selector Thanks!

Comment: @Damkulul: see the updated demo. also id can not start with integer.

Comment: In HTML5 it is possible to use a number as Id

Comment: I tried your new Demo but I get the results from both tables and not from a specific one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58419/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-damkulul).

Comment: It works fine with integer as ID 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222991/can-i-use-an-anchor-id-starting-with-a-number-in-html5

Comment: It will, but that is bad practice. going against rules.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your HTML:

```
<div id="slideHolder">
    <ul id="mainList" ">
        <li templateid="1">
           <div id="div-id1"  >
                <table >
                    <tr>
                      <td>Video</td>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li templateid="2">
            <div id="div-id2" >
                <table>
                    <tr>
                       <td >Text2</td>
                    <td >Image2</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript which retrieves data only from the first table:

```
var tdtexts= $("#div-id1 td").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});

alert("array length: " + tdtexts.length + " first element: " + tdtexts[0] + " second element: " + tdtexts[1]);
```

See that the result is shown in a popup, not in the HTML.

Also note that you cannot have an integer as an `id`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703774/this-id-in-jquery-wont-fetch-the-element-id-if-it-is-a-number-or-contains-numbe).

And here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Et73u/6/).

Comment: Sorry in this demo I get the text from all tables : here is the input:
Video Image
Text Image
I need only from a specific div/li which has a specific Id

Comment: In this demo you are retrieving data only from the first table since the identifier is "1" in the `$("#1 td")` expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can find data as table wise from here

```
$("#mainList table").each(function(){
   $(this).find("td").each(function(){
     return $(this).html();
   });

});
```

Comment: Ok, where do I use the Id of specific table i need (for example I have Id -> 1 and I need to select Table with Id 1 .

Comment: so you can use as like $("#tableId td").each(function(){  return $(this).html(); });